# what cause List.get(128) different

Tags: java, list

```
        int a= p1.get(128);
        int b = p2.get(128);
        if(a == b)  System.out.println("same");   

        if(p1.get(128) == p2.get(128)) System.out.println("same");
```

say I have two list a and b which are elements are 1,2,3... exactly the same,
For above code, I feel unbeliable that if(p1.get(128) == p2.get(128)) is wrong while above is true why?

seems that 127 is a threshold, why?

Comment: Are `p1` and `p2` defined as `List<Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.Integer` keeps an internal cache of objects with values from -128 to 127.  So when you compare auto-boxed instances of `java.lang.Integer` in that range with reference comparisons it will match.

This first expression is true because the two objects came out of the cache and are the same reference:

`Integer a = 127;
Integer b = 127;
a == b`

is equivalent to:

`(Integer.valueOf(127) == Integer.valueOf(127))`

This next comparison is false because it's outside the range that's cached, so each call to valueOf() makes a new object and the pointers don't match

`(Integer.valueOf(128) == Integer.valueOf(128))`

If actually equivalent to

`new Integer(128) == new Integer(128)`

Comment: what does the type for the returning value for list.get()?

Answer (score 4):

`p1` and `p2` are two different objects and hence when you compare them with `==`, the result is false.

But `a` and `b` are primitives and get the values through auto-unboxing. As they are getting the same integer value, therefore `a` & `b` comparison using `==` results in true

Comment: But p1.get() returns an integer right?  
what does the type for the returning value for list.get()?

Comment: @user3495562 this is where auto-unboxing behind the scene convert the Integer to int.

Comment: @user3495562 Integer is an object whereas int is a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is:

`p1.get(128)` returns an `Integer` object, while `p2.get(128)` returns another `Integer` object. These objects have the **same value** but they are **not same objects**.

Therefore,

```
p1.get(128) == p2.get(128);    // is false
```

But,

```
p1.get(128).equals(p2.get(128)); // is true
```

Comment: Then why int a=128, int b=128; a==b is true